# Collection of subsets of Naturals with containment

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question: Let $S$ be a collection of subsets of $\Bbb N$ such that for every $A, B \in S$ we have $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$. Can $S$ be uncountable?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although this is often found to be surprising. To see it, replace $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$, which has the same size, and consider the collection of Dedekind cuts in the rationals.

Comment: Is there any way of doing it without replacing N with Q?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so enumerate it as $\{q_n\mid n\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, and then for each real $r$ consider $A_r=\{n\mid q_n<r\}$. That is what I meant by "replace $\mathbb{N}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$."

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: The following is undoubtedly excessively vague: Is there a natural collection of sets of natural numbers with the desired property?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, here is another way to do it, which you might find to be more natural: Consider the tree $2^{\lt\omega}$ consisting of all finite binary sequences. We may identify nodes in that tree as natural numbers in a natural way, for example, by interpreting them as binary representations (appending a $1$ to address the leading zeros problem). Now, for each infinite binary sequence $s$, let $A_s$ consist of the numbers that lie on $s$ or to the left in that tree under the lexical order. It follows that $s<t\to A_s\subset A_t$.

Comment: Definitely tied more naturally to the integers. Thanks.